# Should askers of deleted questions have access equivalent to what 10K Users have?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

In the interest of providing feedback to askers of questions that have been deleted, should they continue to have access to the question equivalent to what 10K users have to them?

If you aren't a 10K User, if a question is deleted, you have absolutely zero access to the question. You have no way to see the feedback on the question of why it was closed and deleted (since the close reason are why it was deleted).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Users under 10k can only see their own deleted answers. They don't have access to view their deleted questions once they've left the page.

Comment: @animuson: ah, so they'll see a 404 even if they have the URL still?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yep, with the message "voluntarily deleted by its owner".

Comment: @MartijinPieters - I want the ability to see my deleted question the way a 10K User can see my deleted question. I want to see the feedback on it, so I can make it better and understand why it was deleted.